# Jquery help create input field based on another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an input field when the Add input is clicked.

The input created with Jquery should be the same as the closest input field but just with info added to the name.

When the Add input is clicked the text should change to "Remove input" and if it is clicked the created input field should be removed.

My HTML:

```
<div class="input string optional">
<label for="company_count" class="string optional"> count</label>
<input type="text" size="50" name="company[count]" maxlength="255" id="company_count" class="string optional">
<p class="addinput">Add input</p>
</div>

<div class="input string optional">
<label for="company_navn" class="string optional"> Navn</label>
<input type="text" size="50" name="company[navn]" maxlength="255" id="company_navn" class="string optional">
<p class="addinput">Add input</p>
</div>
```

My Jquery

```
    $('.addinput').toggle(function() {


    }
});
```

Update: 
The input field:

```
<div class="input numeric integer optional"><label for="company_prisar" class="integer optional"> Pris 1. år</label><input type="number" step="1" size="50" name="company[prisar]" id="company_prisar" class="numeric integer optional"></div>
```

When the add input is clicked this input is added:

```
<input type="number" step="1" size="50" name="company[prisarinfo]" id="company_prisarinfo" class="numeric integer optional">
```

Comment: I'd imagine you mean [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), not 'toogle()`?

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if you have found it suitable, if not provide more details on how the answer fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct then something like this should solve the problem:

```
$('button.add', '#companyinfo').live('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(this).parents('.input').find('input').last().clone().prop('value','');
    var counter = $(this).parents('.input').find('input').length + 1;
    var newname = element.prop('id') + '_' + counter;
    element.prop('name', newname);
    element.insertAfter($(this).parents('.input').find('input').last());
    $('button.remove').removeProp('disabled');
})
$('button.remove', '#companyinfo').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.input').find('input').last().remove('input');
    if ($(this).parents('.input').find('input').length == 1) {
        $(this).parents('.input').find('button.remove').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Note that I've modified you html a bit, you can see a [working live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/H6XeJ/2/).

Comment: Yes almost what I want, just that the name should be company[closest input field name + info] Example if there is added a input field to with the name company[prisar] the added input field should be company[prisarinfo]. I have updated my post with an example

Comment: I have created this based on your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/H6XeJ/8/ but the info is outside the []

Comment: My new version with few edits: http://jsfiddle.net/H6XeJ/20/ still having the same problem

Comment: this is fixed with regex, check out my modyfied version here where I also limited to max one extra info input field:
http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/gDChA/1/

Comment: When I press add at the first input and then press add and remove on the secound the add button apears again at the first input

Comment: It is not working, because I cannot change my HTML structure to match your example. This is my html structure: http://pastie.org/2363520  oth

Comment: Your html is invalid, namely it has multiply elements with same id. I guess you only posted it as example, but if you expect people to do your work the least you could is to take the time to post some valid html to work on. My answer is easy adaptable to your structure - you should be able to go on from here on your own

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo, it should read:

```
$('p.addinput').toggle(function(){});
```

Could you expand upon what you want the function to do? It's not clear to me.

Comment: I'm hoping to make it an answer with more input from Rails. It seems like he wants to add an additional INPUT when someone clicks on 'Add Input', yet it's not clear if he wants it in it's own DIV or appended to the same DIV next to or before the other INPUT. Just not very clear what he wants.